# Retaining floating point values

Tags: sap-ase

I have a calculation to be done in a query: `((28154/3745181) * 100)`, whose resultant value is `.751739` which I want as `0.75`.

But when I try to do it in a query, I get `0` as shown below:

```
select ((28154/3745181) * 100) --Returns 0 as the result.
```

How can I get the desired `0.75` as the resultant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing integer arithmetic because your types are integer types.

```
select ((cast(28154 as float)/cast(3745181 as float)) * 100)
```

However you are obviously trying to get percentages so this is an alternative:

```
select((100 * 28154) / 3745181 )
```

I.e. do the multiplication first, then the division.